# How to get the minimum mysql row size

Tags: mysql

I am designing a table in MySql (InnoDB) and want to make sure that it takes the absolute minimum space on disk. My question is: does row storage size depend on the order of columns in a table?

For example, here is column order 1:

```
    bigint (8 bytes)
    tinyint (1 byte)
    int (4 bytes)
    int (4 bytes)
    tinyint (1 byte)
```

Is the disk space taken by this table row any different than the one in this case (order 2):

```
    bigint (8 bytes)
    tinyint (1 byte)
    tinyint (1 byte)
    int (4 bytes)
    int (4 bytes)
```

Or perhaps this (order 3):

```
    bigint (8 bytes)
    int (4 bytes)
    int (4 bytes)
    tinyint (1 byte)
    tinyint (1 byte)
```

I recall working in an environment a long time ago where order mattered (it was important to not have fields be positioned across 4-byte boundaries). Does it make a difference in MySQL 5.x?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If storage size is *that* important, maybe you shouldn't pick MySQL, but use a specific size-optimized database or write something yourself. Why is it so important? Disk size is almost free.

Comment: Well, I'm expecting this table to have many millions rows (billions?). I don't know how well MySQL will operate in this scenario, and a byte saved times a billion times is a billion bytes.

Comment: InnoDB takes more space than MyISAM, as InnoDB uses transactions rather than atomic operations, so if you're that concerned about disk usage you may want to consider using MyISAM. You might want to check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-physical-record.html. It doesn't say anything about column order, so my guess would be that it's of no importance.

Comment: But a byte saved on a 1000 byte record is still only 0.1% saved, regardless of the number of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving a byte per record when you have a billion records is indeed a billion bytes, but a byte saved on a 1000 byte record is still only 0.1% saved, regardless of the number of records. It's all relative. :)

If you want to store large amounts of data that you access neither often nor fast, then you might benefit more from a storage facility that actually compresses the data. Maybe you can have a look at the `ARCHIVE` storage engine of MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html

It is a special storage engine that compresses rows when they are inserted. It doesn't have indexes, and it supports only `insert` and `select` (no `delete` and `update`), but for applications that just need to output a lot of data (logging and such) it might be just what you're looking for.